# Fitting a logistic GAM using pygam (example from ESL book)

Tags: python, generalized-additive-model

I was reading the chapter on GAM in ESL (9.1), and wanted to replicate the results of modeling the UCI [spam data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Spambase) using a GAM.

After downloading the file, I prepped the data (did log-transforms following the text):

```py
Xy = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=' ', header=None)
X, y = Xy.iloc[:, :57], Xy.iloc[:, 57]
X2 = np.log(X + 0.1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1536, random_state=42)
```

$X_1$, ..., $X_{54}$ are $100\times$ the percentage of words/characters in an email that matches a certain word/characters. So they range from 0 to 100. After the log(x+0.1) transform the range is log(0.1) = -2.30 to log(100.1) = 4.61. Their histograms look similar - majority of emails does not contain the words (a large bar at -2.30).
[image]

$X_{55}, X_{56}, X_{57}$ are counts of certain sequences, and their histograms look like:
[image]

Next, I tried to fit the model:

```py
from pygam import LogisticGAM
gam = LogisticGAM().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, after waiting a while the output I got was 'did not converge'.

Any help on how to get the solver to converge is greatly appreciated!

Apart from ESL, I spent some time reading the following (in case anyone is interested):
pygam docs (https://pygam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/logisticgam.html), a helpful tutorial by Kim Larsen (https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/07/30/gam/), a lab discussing GAM with GLM and linear models from a course: https://harvard-iacs.github.io/2020-CS109B/labs/lab02/notebook/

Comment: Are all the features continuous measurements? If you've got other types of features (binary, categorical), you'll have to specify them as such in a model formula. This part of the docs discusses how to do this: https://pygam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/tour_of_pygam.html#Functional-Form:

Comment: @MatthewDrury Yes, they are all continuous. There are 57 in total (48 are % of words in the mail that match a given word, 6 are % of ch's that match a given ch, the remaining 3 are length measures).

Comment: Got it. Have you done some EDA on those features? How evenly distributed are they across their range. If you've got a few that only assume a small number of values, you'll have trouble fitting full splines to them.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Thanks for the suggestion! You were right: the majority of the features aren't evenly distributed - there's a large concentration at a single value: 0 or log(0.1) after the transformation. From Kim Larsen's blog (link above) there're 2 ways to estimate GAM params (1) a local scoring algorithm (used in the r package by Hastie and Tibshirani) and (2) penalized iterative reweighted least squares (used in pygam). Since the r package clearly converged on this dataset (as shown in the ESL book), could it be that method (2) doesn't work on this data?